# Google Analytics in Chrome Extension not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

I have created an account on Google analytics, created a property, and a data stream for web.  In my popup.js for the Chrome extension I have the following code:

```
// Standard Google Universal Analytics code
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga'); 

    ga('create', 'G-XXXXXXXXXX', 'auto'); 
    ga('set', 'checkProtocolTask', null); 
    ga('send', 'pageview', '/popup.html'); 


 function trackButtonClick(e) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'Button', 'Click', e.target.id);
  };

  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', trackButtonClick);
  }
```

I can observer in dev tools the request to https://www.google-analytics.com/collect.  But in the google analytics console, I'm not showing any data.  It's been several days since I have first used the tracking code.  What am I doing wrong?  Is it something with the new Google Analytics 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a Google Analytics 4 Property ID (**G-XXXXXXXX**) with `analytics.js` library (***ga***) for Universal Analytics. To use your snippet I suggest you create a Universal Analytics Property (as shown in following image) and use the relative identifier **UA-XXXXXXX-X**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't realize I could still create a UA property and couldn't get the new code to work in the extension.

Comment: It works until 1 June 2023