# Google analytics custom dimension confusion

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to add useful event logging to my webapp. I know it is recommended to use default google analytics events, but my case does not really fit well in the default events.

In the documentation below: why do i need to configure a map with "Index" properties? I would think that i can just use the name configured in the custom dimension in the event parameters? What does this index even refer to?

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the custom dimensions you must first define them in the Property:

[image]

The index indicates the position in the list of your custom dimension that you have defined. So in the Google Analytics snippet you will use the index of the dimension where you want the information to be contained, then in Google Analytics interface you can use the name of that dimension in the reports.

Comment: wow, this all feels like it is unnecessarily complex

Comment: Where do you actually find this page? On the page where i add the custom dimensions, i dont see an "index" field: "All Events" -> "Manage Custom Definitions". I only see "parameter name", "dimension name" and "last changed".

Comment: You are using a GA4 property, so the custom dimension is a parameter. The page of the screenshot is in Universal Analytics.

Comment: I have several websites running in Universal analytics. I am not a big fan of GA4, but apparently i cannot create UA apps anymore?

Comment: You can't create UA Property for app but you can still create it for website.

Comment: Do you know how? I simply could not find a way to do so ... And do you think it is a good idea? I know GA4 is supposed to replace UA, but UA was so much more intuitive.

Comment: Check for example my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64793124/google-analytics-in-chrome-extension-not-working/64793285?noredirect=1#comment114561166_64793285

Comment: Ha ... that options seems to be gone now ... i guess they want people to use GA4

Comment: Show a screenshot, pls. It's curious

Comment: You are looking at your GA4 property settings already created, you have to create a new one Property by clicking on create property. In fact it seemed strange to me that they removed this feature so early.

Comment: Ah, excellent. Recreated it, and now i have both ;)

Comment: Can i bother you with one more practical question? :)

Comment: Yes, but I think it is also appropriate for the sake of moderation to open a new main question

Comment: Created new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64864817/script-to-combine-universal-analytics-and-ga4