# Script to combine universal analytics and GA4?

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to combine universal analytics and GA4 on my new website.

The documentation for GA4 mentions this tracking code:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-123456"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'G-123456');
</script>
```

The documentation for UA mentions this tracking code:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-123456-4"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-123456-4');
</script>
```

The 2 'config' calls look logical to me, but apparently the script is also requested with an 'id' query parameter. How do i properly combine UA and GA4? This is how i have it running now:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-123456"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'G-123456');
    gtag('config', 'UA-123456-4');
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation said to combine these in this way (with `UA-XXXXXX-13` in querystring **not** `G-XXXXXXXXXX`):

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXX-13"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXX-13');
  gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXXX');
</script>
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/basic-tag?technology=gtagjs

Comment: Will having UA-XXX tag in url still work after 1st July when UA expires?

Comment: I assume the code will give no error however in Analytics you will not see the collected data.